# How can I show YouTube view counts under WordPress single.php without any plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to show view counts of YouTube videos as "post view count" in my custom WordPress theme.

I don't want to use any plugins if it is not necessary.

9gag.tv did this years ago but the site is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the YouTube API to fetch view count for a video. :)

Comment: If I could do that with YouTube API without help, I wouldn't have asked the question at the beginning.